# Clocks due to change and sleep prompt goes into infinite loop

Tags: macos, bug, clock

Tonight the clocks change in the UK from BST to GMT. Officially at 2am BST going back to 1am GMT.

At 00:00 my Mountain Lion macbook pro asks me if I want it to sleep.  Usually there's never a problem. Coincidently tonight, all the "cancel" button does is reset the timer back to 10 minutes?!

I decided to press sleep.. thinking it'd get rid of the message. No, it's now worse. I'm guessing the sleep prompt is still loading on the desktop even though I'm on the login screen. I can't type into any input field.

Powering down or restarting doesn't resolve the issue.

Is it stuck like this until 2am?? Any ideas on a fix?

Answer (score 1):

go to guest user
bring up 'monitor' app; I stopped a number of processes, although I can't remember which ones, including finder
bring up 'preferences' > 'energy saver' > 'power adapter' > 'schedule' and turn off sleep schedule

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Ask Different! To make your answer useful to both the OP and future visitors, you should strive for a clearly explained and easily reproduced answer. Adding details to the steps you outlined above, including a rationale ad the correct name the monitoring app, would be a great start.